Nextjs application publishing errors with iis
Good morning, I created an app with iisnode and did all the configuration, but when I try to view it, I get my code from "server.js"...
enter image description here
This is my server.js:
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const port = process.env.PORT || 3080;
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

    if (pathname === "/a") {
      app.render(req, res, "/a", query);
    } else if (pathname === "/b") {
      app.render(req, res, "/b", query);
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});

web.configb:
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" />
  </system.webServer>
  <location path="" overrideMode="Deny">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="\*" modules="iisnode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>

I want to be able to access my next js page

https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-next-js-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Does your project work properly locally? or does the problem only occur in IIS?

I can reproduce your issue with the Web.Config you provided.
There are two main problems:

Remove the \ in verb attribute of iisnode handler.

<handlers>
    <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>

After this, you should get a 500 error with substatus code 1002. Something like this screenshot.

Specifies your environment is a production environment.

<iisnode node_env="production" nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" />

When all is said and done, you should be able to get it working:

